# Angular2 Routing, Routing parameters

Tags: angular, url-routing, token

I've got question some issues with routing parametres on angular2, params are undefined, i will show some code of this project:
it's route.module

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {StudentRegisterComponent} from './student-register/student-register.component';

const routes: Routes = [

    { path: 'student/register', component: StudentRegisterComponent },
    { path: 'student/register/:token', component: StudentRegisterComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: 'student/register', component: StudentRegisterComponent }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class StudentRoutingModule { }
```

and the component file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id.toString(),
    selector: 'student-register',
    templateUrl: 'student-register.component.html'
})
export class StudentRegisterComponent {
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    )
ngOnInit() {
    // subscribe to router event
        let param1 = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['token'];
        console.log('params: ' + param1 );
}
}
```

Is there any way that it could work?

Comment: `RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: 'student/register', component: StudentRegisterComponent }
        ])` sets this particular route and don't use your previous routing table

Comment: Thanks, it could be one of the problem causing this error, I changed this to RouteModule.forRoot([ { path: 'student/register', component: StudentRegisterComponent } ]), but it's still the same situation

Answer (score 3):

You are not using your `Routes` object where the `token` is specified:

Try this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {StudentRegisterComponent} from './student-register/student-register.component';

const routes: Routes = [

    { path: 'student/register', component: StudentRegisterComponent },
    { path: 'student/register/:token', component: StudentRegisterComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(Routes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class StudentRoutingModule { }
```